# Cpp in VSCode with Code Runner - How to compile to other folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm using VS Code to program in C++.
When I run the code (using the "Code Runner" extension), the `.exe` file stored in the same folder.
I've seen in many projects that they stored it in a `/bin` folder.
Is it possible to automatically store it in there? (Also create the `/bin` folder if it doesn't exists).

Comment: You can change the exact command that the code runner executes: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out 2 ways how to do your task:

1. In this scenario you have to create **bin** folder manually

   So let's configure your VScode extension

   From extension page follow this step to open settings

   From extension page follow this step to open settings
   [image]

   In settings tab open "Edit in settings.json"

   [image]

   In your Json find "code-runner.executorMap"::cpp and insert the following command instead of the existing one

   ```
   cd $dir/bin && g++ ../$fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $fileNameWithoutExt
   ```

   So it would look like this
   [image]

   P. S. This command works on Windows, and may not work on linux. I guess If the previous command does not work in linux, then try the next one

   ```
   cd $dir/bin && g++ ../$fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && ./$fileNameWithoutExt
   ```

   And I think, if you're linux user you can automate everything with a command(but unfortunately I can't test it)

   ```
   cd $dir && mkdir -p bin && cd bin && g++ ../$fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && ./$fileNameWithoutExt
   ```
2. In this scenario you have to switch execution  to integrated terminal(so output will change a little bit) by adding to your json following line

   ```
   "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
   ```

   and changing your cpp command to:

   for windows

   ```
   cd $dir && mkdir -Force bin > $null && cd bin && g++ ../$fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt
   ```

   and I guess for linux

   ```
   cd $dir && mkdir -p bin && cd bin && g++ ../$fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt
   ```

   So it would looks like this
   [image]

Comment: Tried this for Mac and it is as follows:

"cpp": "cd $dir && mkdir -p bin && cd bin && g++ ../$fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dirbin/$fileNameWithoutExt",

I hope it's the same in linux

Answer (score 2):

For those who use a /src and /bin separately, here's my solution:

change "cpp": under "code-runner.executorMap": to

```
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o ..\\bin\\$fileNameWithoutExt && ..\\bin\\$fileNameWithoutExt",
```

This creates and runs the .exe from the bin folder within the parent.

Answer (score 1):

If anbody is interested in separating executables to a \bin directory and running the code with external cmd.exe use this (code-runner.executorMap):

```
"c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o .\\bin\\$fileNameWithoutExt && start cmd \"/k ; .\\bin\\$fileNameWithoutExt\""
```

This is for C but is easily modified for C++.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Deumaudit's answer for Linux users,

Create a `bin` folder in your working directory manually.
Now in your `settings.json` file under `"code-runner.executorMap"::cpp` insert the following command instead of the existing one:

```
cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $dir/bin/$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir/bin/$fileNameWithoutExt
```